# Revoke superuser connect a specific database

Tags: postgresql

I have a few databases. I created a superuser for login, but I just want to allow the superuser to log into one specific database. I used

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE mydatabase FROM myuser;
```

This command completes without error, but logins to the database are still not blocked. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special group `PUBLIC` probably still has connect privileges to the database, so the `REVOKE` command you ran has no effect.

But I recommend that you use the `pg_hba.conf` file in your data directory to achieve what you want. These two lines:

```
host  alloweddb  myuser  0.0.0.0/0  md5
host  all        myuser  0.0.0.0/0  reject
```

will allow `myuser` to connect via TCP to `alloweddb`, but will forbid connections to all other databases.

Don't forget to reload the configuration files with `pg_ctl reload` after modifying `pg_hba.conf`.